Podman pod stuck on stopping state
I have RHEL 8.9 system that is runnign podman and has a pod running on it.
After a reboot I've found that one of the containers is in a "stopping" state and since then I cannot do anything on that pod.
That pod has a systemd file, I guess it's connected to the problem
I tried to
sudo podman pod stop <POD>

But it got struck.
sudo podman kill <containter>

fails saying:
Error: container state improper: stopped

Inspecting the container I got it has a PID, but such PID does not exists.
ps -ax

shows that no such PID exists.
sudo kill -9 <PID>


Obviously fails either since  does not exist.
Rebooting had no effects either.
I would like to get rid of the container so I can create the whole pod again.
Is there a way to force a container to die, gracefully or not...

After many tries I finally found a way to get rid of that "stopping container".
The method is quite drastic though...
sudo podman system reset 
sudo podman system prune

This way I got a fresh new podman to start again and has saved my day since I has only one pod running.
I guess that may be a bit extreme if you have many pods or many containers that you may not want to affect.

In able to do this, I also had to delete temporarily my containers.conf and storage.conf at  /home/my_user/.config/containers. Oly then, I was able to follow this advice. I backed up these files and the I copied them again and everything worked! THANKS
